# Why does ocaml ignore one function and does all the rest?

Tags: function, ocaml

So i have this code, which its supposed to give me an yes or no answer. It doesnt give me any errors yet it seems like it doesnt enter my rec func function, which makes it give the wrong answer. Would much apreciate the help

```
let n = read_int()

let () = 
  let valor = ref true in
  let i = ref 1 in
  let a = ref 0 in
  let b = ref 0 in
  let c = ref 0 in
  let e = ref 1 in (* 1 = variavel 0 = conetor*)
         
  let rec func() = 
    i := !i + 1;
    let () = Printf.printf "i" in
    let r = read_line() in 
    if r = "(" then a := !a + 1;
    if r = ")" then b := !b + 1;
    if r = ")" && !e = 1 then valor := false;
    if r = "(" && !e = 0 then valor := false;
    if !b > !a then valor := false;
    if (r = "&" || r = "|" || r = "->" || r = "<->") && (!c > 0 || !e = 1) then valor := false;
    if r = "&" || r = "|" || r = "->" || r = "<->" then e := 1;
    if r = "!" then c := !c + 1;
    if r <> "!" && r <> "(" && r <> ")" && r <> "&" && r <> "|" && r <> "->" && r <> "<->" && !e = 0 then valor := false;
    if r <> "!" && r <> "(" && r <> ")" && r <> "&" && r <> "|" && r <> "->" && r <> "<->" then e := 0;
    if r <> "!" && r <> "(" && r <> ")" && r <> "&" && r <> "|" && r <> "->" && r <> "<->" && !c > 0 then c := 0;
    if !i = n-1 then () else func() in 
    if !e = 1 then valor := false;
    if !c > 0 then valor := false;
    if !a <> !b then valor := false;
    let msg = if !valor then "YES" else "NO" in
    Printf.printf "%s \n" msg
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

Just skimming your code I see a definition of a function named `func` but no calls to this function (other than from inside the function).

I'd say you need to actually call `func`. That should get you started.